# Variable undefined when declared

Tags: javascript, php, variables, request, undefined

```html
if ('all_products' == select_mode) {
  var url = '/wp-content/plugins/wplab-custom-code-master/wplab-custom-code.php';

  var request = jQuery.get(url);
            
  request.done( function( response ) {
    console.log(response);
    checked_items = response;
  });

  request.fail( function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(thrownError);    
  });
}
```

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 

$args = array(
  'numberposts'      => -1,
  'fields'           => 'ids',
  'post_type'        => 'product',
  'post_status'      => 'publish'
);

$product_ids = get_posts( $args );

return $product_ids;
```

When I run the code, the url variable in js code results undefined, but how you can see the variable is declared. Why?

Second, one time the js code works the ajax call returns internal server error. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: "the url variable in js code results undefined" -> where/how do you test for its value? You do assign a value to it so it can't be undefined in that same block.

Comment: Have you check if you have errors in the browser console? Please post the error that gives you. Think that who read have no idea what you want to do with your program....

Comment: The error in the console is an internal server error (error 500) but I can't be able to go back at the error origin.

Comment: I tried to debug the php file and the problem is the function get_posts() that return the right response but after itself destruct. Why? Can you debug the function downloading wordpress solution and debugging a file with get_posts() function.

Answer (score 0):

As for js code, the `url` (in provided code block) cannot be undefined.

You can check it via `console.log` or debugger;

As for 500 error, first thing is to check the route address, where the request was done.

Cannot help about php code.